# YA Fantasy book I read in the 90's. Coming of age, young boy, hunger potion, kobold and girl met on the way. Magic fireworks ending

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

For some reason this book crept back into my memory a few years ago. Getting desperate to find it again. The few details I think I can remember are:

- Boy sets off into a woods
- People he was living with were killed(maybe a fire)
- Boy was inept at magic or the trauma made him inept, maybe even mute for a short time.
- Meets a kobold or some hairy creature that can speak his language, that joins him.
- Meets a girl around his age, some sort of other race like elf, faerie, sprite or something to that effect.

One point he mentions looking for booty and the kobold says something to the effect of "what about that booty" and kicks him in the butt, the girl laughs.

One point they come to a river or lake and recognize they need baths. The girl takes her clothes off with no hesitation, culturally its no big deal to her, this embarrasses the boy.

They possess a hunger potion that one drop cures hunger, and tastes like their favorite food. They are warned to take no more than one drop.

The ending of the book has the characters watching a fireworks display and a magical water dragon over the sea, I believe created by the boy who has become a much more powerful magic caster at this point.

I believe the book had a predominately blue cover, maybe the robed boy on front.